# Lib not included within nested node_modules upon npm install

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, dependencies, node-modules

I am working with 3 React projects, `A`, `B` and `C` where `C` is a dependency of `B` and `B` is a dependency of `A`.

Within `B` I am lazy loading an image from `C`

```
const MyImage = React.lazy(() => import('@company/ProjectC/dist/images/some-image'));
```

From project `B` I see the `node_modules` folder upon running `npm i` and I can see project `C` included and it includes the directory I am referencing above which is great.

The issue comes when I am installing project `B` within `A`...

The error I see in the console is

> Module not found: Can't resolve '@company/projectC/dist/images/some-image' in '/.../projectA/node_modules/@company/projectB/dist/my-file'

Looking at the file in question within the `node_modules` of project `A` I find `my-file` and can see it still has the same lazy loading line, so nothing has changed as expected.

```
var MyImage = react_1.default.lazy(function () { return Promise.resolve().then(function () { return __importStar(require('@company/projectC/dist/images/some-image')); }); });
```

When I look in the `node_modules` of project `A` at the contents of project `B` I can see its own `node_modules` directory, however it seems that there is no mention of project `C`... You can see in the image below that there is only one lib with an `@` prefix, and this is not the `@company` I am expecting...

[image]

Is there a reason why it would not be included here?

For extra clarity, project `C` is also a dependency within project `A` as this is a component library, and I can see all the necessary directories required from here... Would including `C` in both places cause this?

For extra visualisation:

[image]

Comment: try to uninstall the node_modules from project `A`  and then install project `C` into it .

Comment: @nuser137 C installs into it fine.